# LDAP - Difference between apt-get and build from sources installation

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to setup openLDAP with Berkeley Database backend in Ubuntu. The server is remote, so I have to use an ssh client (secureCRT).

What is the difference between installing through (`apt-get install slapd ldap-utils`) and building from sources (`make & make install`) ?

Some website said the command line installation prompts a window to set a password, so it can't be installed through secureCRT, I tried, but no windows were prompted.

After the command line installation, can I set/modify the admin password and the db backend type by changing the configuration file using secureCRT ? Will it lead to the same result of reconfiguration ?

Comment: so, will i get the same software installed  in  the two different install ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get the exact same installation.

Installing a Debian package via `apt-get` script is *roughly* the same as building it via 'make & install', BUT apt scripts usually provide additional post-install scripts, tweaks and configuration files to better comply with the system.

Using or not an SSH client to run the installation should not make any difference in this case.

*After the command line installation, can I set/modify the admin password and the db backend type by changing the configuration file using secureCRT ?*

Yes, you will be able to do it in both cases (apt/make install).

The only thing you should check is your system compatibility with your backend requirement. Here an important thing to note, quoted from [doc](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/install.html) :

> OpenLDAP's slapd(8) BDB and HDB deprecated database backends require
>   Oracle Corporation's Berkeley DB. If not available at configure time,
>   you will not be able to build slapd(8) with these deprecated database
>   backends.
>
> Your operating system may provide a supported version of Berkeley DB
>   in the base system or as an optional software component. If not,
>   you'll have to obtain and install it yourself. Berkeley DB is
>   available from Oracle Corporation's Berkeley DB download page if
>   required.

If your system does provide Berkeley DB and unless you are already comfortable with openLDAP configuration, I strongly recommend to prefer 'apt' over 'make' to run your installation.

Comment: Thanks for your modify and  answer . I checked the Ubuntu, there is no Berkeley DB installed in it in default, so i doubt  OpenLDAP using apt install will work well when set the db backend type to Berkeley . Also i checked the config files of both cases, there are difference in file's format and items.

Comment: Yes actually there are 2 different but equivalent configuration modes : the `slapd-config` system provides special ldap operations to the command line, whereas the deprecated but still very usable `slapd.conf` system is a configuration file. The thing to remember is that switching from one to the other config mode can be a real pain in the ass. But the config mode does not impact the config in itself, whatever the backend setting is for example (except for adding/removing overlays). So you just need to install Oracle's Berkely DB manually on your system prior to run apt-get install.

Comment: The OpenLDAP use the BerkeleyDB by default, so if i don't install BerkeleyDB manually, it won't work well after the apt install and configuration?

Comment: *The OpenLDAP use the BerkeleyDB by default* -> Where did you find this information ? As far as I know, OpenLDAP's *Lightning Memory-Mapped Database (LMDB)*, aka *mdb*, is supposed to have replaced the preferred backend, and *bdb* as well as *hdb* are now deprecated, except on some Red Hat distributions on which bdb is still default. But anyway, if you rely on bdb then installing it manually in the first place is not an option.